# Install and launch ipa signed for ad-hoc distribution from commandline on device

Tags: ios, iphone, command-line, ipa

I am looking for a way to install and launch, an ipa which is signed for ad-hoc distribution, directly on the device, from the commandline (on a non-jailbroken device)

All I need to do is just start the app, not debug it, using command-line (The example app makes a set of api calls, which I want to automate using command-line).

I have tried using [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy). But the requirement specifies that it needs a valid iOS Development certificate installed.

Using

```
ios-deploy --justlaunch --bundle ./example.app
```

it installs the app, but it's not able to start it. (`lldb` fails with `Application has not been launched`).

I suspect it's due to ipa being built for ad-hoc distribution, because if I run the .app file without any signing, the above command just works, and launches the app.

Is this even possible?
Can using instruments to perform some kind of dummy tests help? I have not been successful in doing this.

I think testing tools like appium runs tests on ad-hoc signed ipas, but I am not sure how they do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering on my own. Open to better methods.

Since I wanted to just launch the ad-hoc app, without lldb, I toyed around launching a bundle id from a separate UITest(independent of my archived ipa) using the [`XCUIApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2879415-init). This was what I wanted.

Ultimately I ended up using `ios-deploy` to install the app on the device, and then using facebook's [webdriver agent](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent), through which I could control launching and killing the app, using just curl requests. It uses XCUIApplication under the hood, but provides a lot of other things as well.

Comment: @kamehameha- Thanks for putting up the answer. I am also trying to do the similar thing but struggling to use the webdriver agent without xcode. How did you create the .ipa file of webdriver-agent to install in iphone for testing with curl request. Can you please provide the steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not create an .ipa file of the webdriver-agent. I installed my ipa on the device(using ios-deploy), then used xcodebuild command to run webdriver-agent (I think I needed to sign the webdriver agent as well, since I needed to the run on device) which ultimately started my app. Lookup the commands from [here](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/wiki/Starting-WebDriverAgent)

Comment: @iOSDev All the webdriver agent needs to know is the bundle-id of the ipa that's installed, which can be done through curl requests. Have a look at their [queries page](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/wiki/Queries#starting-session-and-launching-application)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am able to use xcodeBuild in Mac with webdriver agent. Is it possible to use the same procedure in Windows System? I am trying to install XcodeBuild in Windows but i think the support isn't there?

Comment: Well, you can't use it on windows as it is. I would think you'd need to run a mac box inside a virtualbox in windows and run xcodebuild on that(I don't think the latest mac images would be available as well). Can't help much in that regard

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the help. Regards.